# typeahead on Bootstrap 3.0 using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js

I'm using Bootstrap ver. 3.0 on my site.
I want to use the [typeahead.js](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js) and take the data **remotely** from the server ***using ajax***. Although there are many answers *regarding* the issue, I can't find a simple and working code example of how to do it...

BTW, i'm also using jQuery, if that matters.

Thanks!

Comment: But what is the issue ?

Comment: Here's a simple tutorial: http://www.edselmatt.com/2015/02/typeahead-implementation-in-phpmysql.html. It is implemented in PHP.